# Create Custom StepView Design

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I need to create design as below image. In that image it Step View track Weekly Report.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCcvd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a graph using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library, and for steps, you can use Recycler View which contains seven items and it will scroll horizontally.